# Why InnoDB tablespace files gets corrupted?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, tablespace

MySql tables got corrupted with the following error,

```
016-05-17 09:57:07 30503 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace mysql/innodb_index_stats uses space ID: 2 at filepath: ./mysql/innodb_index_stats.ibd. Cannot open tablespace t0db/be_command_log which uses space ID: 2 at filepath: ./t0db/be_command_log.ibd
2016-05-17 09:57:07 7f3fa1f3c7e0  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
```

I have found multiple blogs and answers about fixing this issue and I myself got it recovered from it by dropping and recreating the tables.

But, here I am more interested in knowing *what has caused this corruption?*

I got this corruption when I,
I had just loaded the latest Firmware on my cluster and had powered down all nodes in preparation for rebooting them to activate the new FW. I powered up a node, but crm_mon showed MySql error. Upon investigation I found the error was due to the corrupted tablesspace files.

Please help me in getting the reasoning behind this corruption.

Cheers!

Comment: Database corruption happens.  Errors in the database code (rare), stray cosmic rays, improper database shutdown.  I'm sure others can come up with outer examples.  Anything that can fail, will.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, So do you mean to say its unavoidable? And when you say improper db shutdown, I think it is db that handles it. we only configure it for proper shutdowns and start.

Comment: Improper database shutdown -> Abruptly losing power on the database server.  It's one reason why all servers should have uninterruptible power supplies.

Comment: Check the directories, files, and their ownership and permissions.  `2`  means "No such file or directory".